# Как узнать был ли передан именованный аргумент со значением, совпадающим со значением по умолчанию

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Есть небольшая функция:

```
def foo(*args, unique=False):
    output_str = 'foo('
    for i in range(len(args)):
        output_str = output_str + str(args[i])
        if i != len(args) - 1:
            output_str = output_str + ', '
    if unique and args:
        output_str = output_str + ', unique=True'
    elif unique and not args:
        output_str = output_str + 'unique=True'
    output_str = output_str + ')'
    print(output_str)
```

Мне нужно узнать, был ли передан аргумент unique=False или было использовано значение по умолчанию (идентичное тому, что могли передать) чтобы вывести строку подобную строке которой была вызвана функция. Например, возможны 3 ситуации вызова этой функции:

1. foo(1, 2)
2. foo(1, 2, unique=True)
3. foo(1, 2, unique=False)

- Первый и второй случаи работают и печатают строку которой была вызвана функция в коде:

1. `foo(1, 2)` выводит 'foo(1, 2)'
2. `foo(1, 2, unique=True)` выводит 'foo(1, 2, unique=True)'

- а для 3-го случая:

3. `foo(1, 2, unique=False)` выводит 'foo(1, 2)', когда желаемый вывод 'foo(1, 2, unique=False)'

Comment: То, чего вы хотите, невозможно. При вызове функции функция получает только аргументы, не зная, каким способом она была вызвана. Это имеет силу не только для Питона, но и для всех языках программирования, т.к. аргументы передаются как голые значения в стеке или в регистрах процессора.

Comment: Мне больше интересно, зачем вам это вдруг нужно

Comment: Используйте декоратор для перехвата аргументов вызываемой функции.